# Full background image, ignoring the sites structure?

Tags: css, background-image

I have got a website that looks like this:

```
<div id="top" class="header-container2">...</div>
<div class="main-container">...</div>
```

The first div is the header section and the second the main content area with products and so on. Now I want a full background image and I tried like this:

```
html {
    background: url(someimage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Did not work, no image shown. On the body element it does not work either. Only when I assign the exact same CSS to the `main-container` div, it works, but the image is not shown as background on the div with id `top` of course. So, how could I assign the background image without having to think about the structure of the site? Possible at all?

I double checked the path of the image, so thats not the problem.

Comment: make sure you are giving the right path of the image.

Comment: The path is correct, I double checked

Comment: Can you add a [MCVE]?

Comment: yes first you need to put your code and share the link so i will be able to fix it.

Comment: put it on code pen

Comment: try `#top{}` instead of `html{}` in your css.

Comment: Adding the background image to the #top element worked! Thanks, solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `html` `height` to `100vh` or `100%`

```
html {
    background: url(someimage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

These are the default `CSS` which we set on top of, while writing custom styles like `body`,`html` to `100%`

And also its good to provide minimal `HTML` and `CSS` of your working code.

Answer (score 0):

first, make sure your two divs don't have a `background` property, otherwise you can simply englobe them in a containing div and assign the `background` to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the body, I think. Do you use any CSS resets?

```css
body {
    background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1227511/pexels-photo-1227511.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
div {background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);margin-bottom:10px;padding:10px;}
```

```html
<div id="top" class="header-container2">header-container2</div>
<div class="main-container">main-container</div>
```

To make the page cover the window height, you might try:

```
html, 
body {
    height: 100%;
}
```